# Place a grid of pictures (2x2) with captions

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have 4 photos that I would like to place in in grid on my pages and add a caption to each photo. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package.

Comment: Ah so easy, thx!